# validate with inlineditbox and dgrid

Tags: dojo

I searched for a widget to validate forms and found only `validateTextBox widget`, but I need a widget to validate the `inlineEditBox` and the Dgrid.
Is there any validation tools other than `validateTextBox` that do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, both InlineEditBox and dgrid should be able to use ValidationTextBox, I think. Did you try something like:

```
A <span data-dojo-type="dijit/InlineEditBox" 
        data-dojo-props="editor:'dijit/form/ValidationTextBox', 
            editorParams:{regExp:'\\w+'}">chicken</span> crossed the road.
```

Comment: this worked for me in the text box, but not with the select input.
how should I know this stuff without asking? where was this published? because my problem with dojo is more to find answers all the time!